# TCL, extract 2 integers from string into list?

Tags: string, list, integer, tcl

I have 2 string formatted as such:

```
(1234, 4567)
```

And I have a list

```
points {0 1 2 4}
```

I would like to extract 2 integers from the first list and replace the first two integers in the list, after that extract two more integers from the 2nd list and replace the 3rd and 4th integers in the list so at the end I will have a list of 4 integers from the two strings.

So far I have tried all kind of things but always end up with errors or brackets in the list which I do not want. I feel I am missing out on the easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first set of values, you can parse with `scan` or `regexp`; in this case, I think `scan` looks better:

```
set input "(1234, 5678)"
scan $input "(%d,%d)" a b
```

To update a Tcl list (formally, one in a variable), you use `lset`; you can give a sequence of (zero-based) indices to it to navigate into the exact place in the list where you want to update:

```
set workingArea "points {0 1 2 4}"
lset workingArea 1 2 $a
lset workingArea 1 3 $b

puts $workingArea
# prints: points {0 1 1234 5678}
```